# GUI design in GTK

Tags: ruby, gtk

I am trying to use GTK with Ruby 2.0.0 to design a user interface that looks like this:

```
ColHead1                         ColHead2
(box for user number input)      (box for user number input)

                               SubmitBtn
```

Based on the GTK tutorials I read I got this far:

```
require 'gtk3'

class RubyApp < Gtk::Window

def initialize
    super   
    init_ui
end

def init_ui   

    table = Gtk::Table.new 2, 2, true
    submit = Gtk::Button.new :label => "Submit Btn"

    submit.signal_connect "clicked" do
        on_submit
    end 

    label = Gtk::Label.new "ColHead1"

    entry = Gtk::Entry.new
    entry.signal_connect "key-release-event" do |w, e|
        on_key_release w, e, label
    end

    set_title "Gtk::Entry"
    signal_connect "destroy" do 
        Gtk.main_quit 
    end  

    table.attach label, 0,1,0,1
    table.attach submit, 1, 0, 1, 0

        add table

    set_default_size 250, 200
    set_window_position :center

    show_all        
end  
=begin    
def on_key_release sender, event, label
    label.set_text sender.text
end
=end    
end

Gtk.init
window = RubyApp.new
Gtk.main
```

Can someone explain how to correctly implement the example gui I have shown above?

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? What is "this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have two choices:

1. Encapsulate different containers:

Create a vertical box (Gtk::Box), add to it an horizontal box in which you add Col1 widget and Col2 widget.
Then add your Submit button to the vertical box.

The vertical Box should be added to the main window. This way, you can configure easily how each widgets will fill in theirs allocated spaces.

2. Use a Gtk grid (which is the replacement of Gtk Table)